# Strange behavior of await

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have an async method like this

```
public async Task<bool> FooAsync() 
{ 
    return await SomeThirdPartyLib.SomeMethodReturningBoolAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

I then have code that invokes this in a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ok &= await FooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

In my case this will hang my process after 2 or 3 or another amount of cycles. But when I change the code to

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ok &= await FooAsync()
        .ContinueWith(t => {
            if (t.IsCompleted)
            {
                return t.Result;
            }
            return false;
        })
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

the exact same code works. Any ideas?

**Edit**: I just changed my sample code a little bit to show what `FooAsync` does in principle. In reply to some already given answers and comments: I don't know exactly what `SomeMethodReturningBoolAsync` does. The fact that my `ContinueWith` in fact does nothing useful strucked me.

Comment: How is your method/routine being called and what does `FooAsync` do internally? Are you mixing `.Result` with `await` in the call stack?

Comment: If you are using the `await` keyword it's not parallel. Create a list of tasks and run `foreach(var task in await Task.WhenAll(tasks)`

Comment: @cSteusloff What makes you think the work is *supposed* to be done in parallel?

Comment: Your first version doesn't handle exceptions. Also, can you define more precisely how your process is hanging (never ends, just a temporary freeze, UI stuck or asynchronous task stuck) ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The output will be `Completed` in all runs.

Comment: @Guillaume That's right. The point here is that no exception happen when I run the second version. I also thought that some exception might by hidden due to async and that brought me to my second sample. That is the strange thing here.

Comment: @Igor I updated the sample. I don't know what you mean by "mixing". I don't think I'm mixing stuff here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `FooAsync()` despite the name, is actually doing its work synchronously, so since you're starting your work on the UI thread, it will continue to do all of the work on the UI thread.

When you add in the `ContinueWith` you're forcing a method (that does nothing productive) to run on a thread pool thread, so only the first `FooAsync` call is actually running on the UI thread.  All subsequent calls will be on a thread pool thread as a result of `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

The *correct* fix is to actually adjust `FooAsync` so that it actually does its work asynchronously, rather than synchronously, or if it doesn't do any conceptually asynchronous work, then it should be a *synchronous* method, not return a `Task`, and be called with `Task.Run` in your method here, since it needs to do that synchronous work in another thread.

Comment: How do you know my FooAsync does nothing async? I just left out the code for simplifying things. It's actually calling an async method from a 3rd party framework. Does this change your answer?

Comment: @sprinter252 It's the only explanation that fits the behavior.  I agree that your omission of relevant information from the question does indeed force any answers to be a guess, and that if you want an answer that *doesn't* need to be a guess you should actually provide a complete example in your question.  That said, your comment doesn't change my answer, no.  That you call out to another task returning method doesn't make your method async, it just means that *that* method that you're calling out to is itself returning its result synchronously.

Comment: I updated my question. I just want to say that it seems to me very odd that adding `ContinueWith` solves a problem. Because I don't know what this async 3rd party does this would mean that I should add `ContinueWith` to any of my `await`s to be sure not to end with deadlocks like in my first call.

Comment: @sprinter252 Saying that a method does nothing but call another method doesn't actually add any relevant information to the question.  It's effectively begging the question.  Like I said in my answer, no, the correct solution to the problem is not to call `ContinueWith` all over the place.  That's masking the underlying problem, not solving it.  The problem is that you're doing work synchronously that you think is being done asynchronously.  The solution is therefore to actually do the work asynchronously.  Adding `ContinueWith`s all over the place doesn't do that.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. So you mean wrapping my second call inside let's say a `Task.Run()` should solve the problem?

Comment: @sprinter252 If I'm correct in my diagnosis, then yes, you should be wrapping the long running synchronous work in a call to `Task.Run`, or perhaps the API you're calling needs to be called in a different manner in order to behave (inherently) asynchronously.  No one can really say for sure without knowing the specifics of what you're doing though.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Your suggestion worked. I added `Task.Run(async () => await FooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); }).Wait()` and it's working now.

Comment: @sprinter252 You should not be synchronously blocking on the task.  That's *very bad*.  There's also no reason at all for the lambda to be `async`.  You're also calling the wrong method with `Task.Run`.  You should be going to the *lowest level possible* and finding the operation that needs to be run in another thread.  `FooAsync` is designed to be an asynchronous method and is written accordingly.

Comment: So I'm really lost know. If we assume that the 3rd party thing is working perfectly async. Could you please post a code snippet that solves the problem of calling it 10 times and retrieving `true` if every run was successful? `FooAsync` is needed because it does some more stuff (preparation) which I omitted (like other parts) to avoid confusion.

Comment: @sprinter252 "If we assume that the 3rd party thing is working perfectly async."  We're assuming no such thing.  The behavior you've shown indicates the opposite, in fact.  The code you've shown *would* work, if it was actually asynchronous (and you're description of the behavior is accurate).  If the method *is* properly asynchronous, then you both have a bug somewhere on the caller side, and you didn't accurately describe what's happening.

Comment: Wouldn't that be rendering it completely useless to flag a method `async` in it's signature?

When I actually have no way to trust that signature, any call I want to do asynchronously for sure would have be wrapped in a `Task.Run` to spawn a new thread (which in itself might spawn a new thread if it actually _is_ asynchronous). In that case, what's the whole point of the `async` `await` syntactic sugar?

Comment: @Nasto Indeed, the signature is lying in such a case, and it's a *really* bad idea, but that appears to be what someone did anyway (perhaps by mistake, perhaps not, it's hard to say without specifics).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is inside your question, what happened explain you Servy jet - just start in thread pool:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 ok &= await Task.Run(() => { return FooAsync(); }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Although I think it's not completely correct because FooAsync() is not awaited here isn't it?

Comment: @sprinter252 - here awaited for Task.Run() completed - and this is awaited while FooAsync has ended, in general you are right - FooAsync working as sync code - but together all working as expected ...

Comment: I just wanted to say that your current sample calls `FooAsync` without caring about the result. I think the curlies should be taken out but I don't want to edit the answer :-).

Comment: Oh - sorry - of course you are right - thanks, I have edit my answer !